# Cauchy-Riemann conditions and vector fields

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

Can Cauchy-Riemann conditions of Complex Functions valid for vector fields, I observe when vector fields are irrotational and incompressible they possess a result similar to Cauchy-Riemann conditions. Does this imply that every analytic function us divergentless and irrotational?

Answer (score 1):

When a vector field $\mathbf{u}$ is irrotational ($\nabla \times \mathbf{u}=0$) there is a potential $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi = \mathbf{u}$. The condition for incompressibility $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}=0$ leads then to $\nabla^2 \phi = 0$, i.e., the potential of an irrotational and incompressible vector field is a solution of the Laplace equation (i.e., it's a harmonic equation). Also, any [complex analytical (or holomorphic) function is also a solution of the Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation#Analytic_functions). Therefore, one can say that the Cauchy-Riemann conditions for complex functions and the condition of incompressibility and irrotationality of a vector field are two faces of the same coin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you split a complex analytic (i.e. holomorphic) function 
$$f(z) = u(x, y) + i\, v(x, y) \, \text{ where } \, z = x + i\, y  \in \mathbb{C}$$
into real part $\text{ Re}f(z) = u(x,y)$ and imaginary part $\text{ Im}f(z) = v(x,y)$, 
and form the vector field $$\vec{V}(x,y) = v(x, y) \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, - \, u(x, y) \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$ then that vector field $\vec{V}(x,y)$ has zero curl and zero divergence:
$$\nabla \times \vec{V}  = \vec{0} \,\text{ and } \, \nabla \circ \vec{V} = 0$$ A vector field with the latter two properties, zero curce and zero divergence, is called a harmonic vector field.

And vice versa: if you have a 2D harmonic vector field
$$\vec{V}(x,y) = a(x, y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + b(x, y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
i.e. $\vec{V}$ has zero curl and zero divergence, then its components are the real and the imaginary part of a holomorphic function: more precisely, the function 
$$f(z) = b(x, y) - i\, a(x, y) \, \text{ where } \, z = x + i\, y  \in \mathbb{C}$$  is a complex analytic (i.e. holomorphic) function.

*Proof:* Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: "$\vec{V}(x,y) = v(x, y) \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, - \, u(x, y) \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$" doesn't seem to be right - I think you should either swap $u$ and $v$ or negate one component, but not do both.